# Can't "Copy" scratchpad to DS18B20 EEPROM

Tags: onewire

Im trying to make use of two bytes of DS18B20 EEPROM.
(Actually I use the trusted copy UMW18B20, what have 5 bytes of EEPROM by datasheet.)

The issue: bytes successfully written to the scratchpad, but at "COPY" command - nothing happens. Sensor begins answer with "1" immediately.
After the powerdown or "RECALL" command, the default 0\85 values are loaded.

I'm almost sure, it is not a code issue, nor in data, byte orders, commands, delays and etc. All other commands and data get no issues at all.

I've tried to make huge delays, like 1-10 secs after the "COPY" command.

I suspect that I have a 'fake' or broken part (too lazy to solder another one).

The only one clue is - the sensor begins to answer with "1" immediately after the COPY. There is no any reasonable delay. The very first bit already reads as "1".

I really can't post source, due it is too huge. (It is C++, UART driver, one-wire DSL and DS18B20 controller.) But here is DSL sequence, the actions are pretty obvious (every pause is a 100 μs delay):

```cpp
static constexpr uint8_t ACTIONS_WRITE[] =
{
    Action::PRESENCE,
    Action::SEND, 1, Command::ROM_SKIP,
    Action::SEND, 1, Command::WRITE,
    Action::SEND_USER, 3,
    Action::PRESENCE,
    Action::SEND, 1, Command::ROM_SKIP,
    Action::SEND, 1, Command::READ,
    Action::RECEIVE, 9,
    Action::CHECK_DALLAS_CRC8, 8,
    Action::VERIFY_RECEIVED, 3, 2,
    Action::PRESENCE,
    Action::SEND, 1, Command::ROM_SKIP,
    Action::SEND, 1, Command::EEPROM_COPY,
    Action::PAUSE, 200,
    Action::PAUSE, 200,
    Action::END
};
```

Comment: I found this hint for the Copy Scratchpad command in the datasheet: "If the device is being used in parasite power mode, within 10μs (max) after this command is issued the master must enable a strong pullup on the 1-Wire bus for at least 10ms as described in the Powering the DS18B20 section."

Comment: Yes. But it is what i do. (Anyway im not using parasitic power).

Comment: Make sure that you are following the specifications and timing requirements outlined in the datasheet of the DS18B20 sensor. Sometimes discrepancies between the datasheet and the actual behavior of a component can indicate that it's not genuine.  You can check all the details here: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2019/01/introduction-to-ds18b20.html